# How to have the total sum of all the numbers contained in a matrix?

Tags: scala

I'm a beginner in Scala and I'm trying to build a function that calculates the total sum of all the numbers contained in a matrix.
I tried to do this code :

```
val pixels = Vector(
Vector(0, 1, 2),
Vector(1, 2, 3)
)

def sum(matrix: Vector[Vector[Int]]): Int = {
matrix.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
}

println(sum(pixels))
```

But I get the following error: "value + is not a member of Vector[Int]"

I would like to have the sum total of all the numbers contained in the matrix as an integer.

Can you help me to solve this problem ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `pixels.map(_.sum).sum` is more simple and efficient than reduce, flatten and most of others solutions

Comment: The goal for me was to practice using the reduce function, but I thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `matrix` as a `Vector` of `Vectors`, so arguments to `reduce` are two `Vectors`, not ints. If you want to sum the all, you need to `flatten` first to pull the actual ints from the inner vectors. Also your function the way you wrote it does not return anything. You don't want that variable assignment:

`def sum(matrix: Vector[Vector[Int]]) = matrix.flatten.reduce(_ + _)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know flatten at all.
This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks again!